# jQuery dropdown advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to build a quick dropdown prototype with jQuery and I'm probably at the limit of my jQuery knowledge so I was hoping for some help in solving my problem.

What I'm aiming to achieve: when the user hovers over a link, a dropdown animates down, when the user clicks another link, the next dropdown animates over the top and so on.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="dropdowns">
            <ul>
                <li class="call"><a href="#">Call</a></li>
                <li class="chat"><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
                <li class="message"><a href="#">Send a message</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slide call-panel">
            <h1>Call now</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide chat-panel">
            <h1>Online chat</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide message-panel">
            <h1>Send us a message</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdowns {
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.call a {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.chat a {
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

.message a {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.call-panel {
    height: 300px;
    background: darkgrey;
    display: none;
}

.chat-panel {
    height: 300px;
    background: darkgrey;
    display: none;
}

.message-panel {
    height: 300px;
    background: darkgrey;
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$( ".call a" ).click(function() {
  toggleSlides( ".call-panel" );
});

$( ".chat a" ).click(function() {
  toggleSlides( ".chat-panel" );
});

$( ".message a" ).click(function() {
  toggleSlides( ".message-panel" );
});

function toggleSlides(slide){
    $(".slide").slideUp ( "slow", function(){
        $(slide).slideDown( "slow" );
    } );
}
```

I've set up a quick fiddle here of what I have currently, but as you'll see it's not quite working how I intended, I'm getting animations coming up rather than down, some crazy repeat animations, all sorts - any help would be great!

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/2zwjZ/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/bobthyasian/2zwjZ/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with jquery `this.hash;`

```
$('.dropdowns li a').removeClass('active');
$('.dropdowns li a').click(function(){
   var tabDiv = this.hash;
    $('.slide').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active');
   $(tabDiv).slideDown();
    return false;
});
```

**[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/2zwjZ/1/)**